# Get element inside of outside of function

Tags: javascript

When manipulating DOM elements, is it faster to get them inside the function they are used, or just get them all at once and declare them as globals? For example, if we have to use an element with the ID `'order'` multiple times,

would this be faster,

```
var ORDER = document.getElementById('order');
function test() {
    ORDER.onchange = // manipulate ORDER
}
```

or is this faster

```
function test() {
   var ORDER = document.getElementById('order');
   ORDER.onchange = // manipulate ORDER
}
```

I'm asking because it's usually bad practice to declare so many global variables, but I can't help but think that getting an element once and assigning it to a global variable would be faster than getting it again and again for each function call.

Comment: Polluting the global namespace is never a good idea IMHO. The performance of `getElementById()` is good enough that you should not have to worry about this.

Comment: Or you can keep `ORDER` outside of function, but wrap everything inside a self calling anonymous function.

Comment: Even tho the first method is fast, it depends on what you actually need to achieve. If `order` is constant throughout the application then first approach is good. But if `order` is going to change at any time while application is running, then second approach will give you more accurate results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `document.getElementById` just once is faster than calling it every time. But `getElementById` should be a pretty fast function, so unless you're calling this function in an inner loop, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

You know what Knuth said about [premature optimization](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth), right?

Answer (score 1):

First one would be faster because the `ORDER` variable is already hoisted and has a value assigned to it.

So, when you call the function the function executes faster.

Also, when you put that in a function, each time it is called, `getElementById()` is also called which is bad!

The above is for faster or slower.

But make sure your variable names don't pollute global namespace much as @Fred said!

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends of the use you will give them.

- If you have to use the same elements a lot of times in your code, it's
  better to get once, this way you only inspect the DOM tree one time.
  Plus, you save lines of code. Anyway, always will suppose a better
  performance.
- Otherwise, if you use these elents, one, twice... you can get it each
  time...

In my opinion, I prefer the first option. It suppose a better perfomance and a cleanest code.